# Regex (.NET) to validate any real number

Tags: regex, validation, floating-point, numbers

I am working on a unique regex rule able to validate any real number in two different formats:

**Dots (thousands) and comma (decimal)**

```
123 ; 1.234.567 ; 12.345.678 ; 123.456.789 ; 1.234.567,89 ; 1.234,56789 ; 1,2 ; 0,123
```

**Commas (thousands) and dot (decimal)**

```
1,234,567 ; 12,345,678 ; 123,456,789 ; 1,234,567.89 ; 1,234.56789 ; 1.2 ; 0.123
```

There are some others restriction to take care: the number can be in the middle of a phrase, it can have marks (+,-,+/-,±) at the beginning and potential (e,exp,^) at the end.

I already created a post on this purpose, and the final solution is here:

```
(^|\s)[±+-]?\d{1,3}(?:(e|E|exp)\d+)?($|\s)|(^|\s)[±+-]?(?:([1-9]{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*|[0])(?:,\d*)?(?:(e|E|exp)\d+)?)($|\s)|(^|\s)[±+-]?(?:([1-9]{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|[0])(?:\.\d*)?(?:(e|E|exp)\d+)?)($|\s)
```

Everything works OK so far. However, I found a problem when the number is at the end of a phrase ending in dot (.) or comma (,) or any other character. It doesn't detect the number anymore.

Simple test case: "My numbers are 123,456,789.89, 0.123 and 123.456.789,89."

Notice that the only thing that fix the problem is to add a white space just next to the number. I have tried to create a replacement regex rule to add a white space between the number and the next character. No success...

Could anyone help me again, please?

Comment: Yes! This is a new question!

Comment: @RahulTripathi The question is not the same here, it adds context, which was not included when I first answered OP's question

Comment: Try [`(?<=^|\s)[±+-]?\d{1,3}(?:(?:[eE](?:xp)?)\d+)?(?=[.,]*(?:$|\s))|(?<=^|\s)[±+-]?(?:(?:[1-9]{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*|[0])(?:,\d*)?(?:(?:[eE](?:xp)?)\d+)?)(?=[.,]*(?:$|\s))|(?<=^|\s)[±+-]?(?:(?:[1-9]{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|0)(?:\.\d*)?(?:(?:[eE](?:xp)?)\d+)?)(?=[.,]*(?:$|\s))`](http://goo.gl/5G7CGL). Please do not copy/paste the regex pattern, check it by clicking the link in the comment. Copy/paste the pattern from regexstorm only.

Comment: @NullPointers: Any feedback?

Comment: Thanks!! It does the job very good. Awesome job! :D

Comment: Yes, just let me write the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adjusting the trailing boundaries that you have as `($|\s)` into lookaheads like `(?=[,.]*(?:$|\s))` that will check (but not consume) if there is a `.` or `,` followed with a  whitespace or end-of-string right after the number:

```
(?<=^|\s)[±+-]?\d{1,3}(?:(?:[eE](?:xp)?)\d+)?(?=[.,]*(?:$|\s))|(?<=^|\s)[±+-]?‌​(?:(?:[1-9]{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*|[0])(?:,\d*)?(?:(?:[eE](?:xp)?)\d+)?)(?=[.,]*(?:$|\s‌​))|(?<=^|\s)[±+-]?(?:(?:[1-9]{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|0)(?:\.\d*)?(?:(?:[eE](?:xp)?)\d+)?‌​)(?=[.,]*(?:$|\s))
```

You can also shorten the code and enhance it a bit by replacing `(e|E|exp)` with `(?:[eE](?:xp)?`. All the non-capturing groups may be turned into capturing ones, but using the `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` you can still get a clean Match object.

```
(?<=^|\s)[±+-]?\d{1,3}([eE](xp)?\d+)?(?=[.,]*($|\s))|(?<=^|\s)[±+-]?(([1-9]{1,3}(\.\d{3})*|0)(,\d*)?([eE](xp)?\d+)?)(?=[.,]*($|\s))|(?<=^|\s)[±+-]?(([1-9]{1,3}(,\d{3})*|0)(\.\d*)?([eE](xp)?\d+)?)(?=[.,]*($|\s))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5cs)%5b%c2%b1%2b-%5d%3f%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d(%5beE%5d(xp)%3f%5cd%2b)%3f(%3f%3d%5b.%2c%5d*(%24%7c%5cs))%7c(%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5cs)%5b%c2%b1%2b-%5d%3f((%5b1-9%5d%7b1%2c3%7d(%5c.%5cd%7b3%7d)*%7c0)(%2c%5cd*)%3f(%5beE%5d(xp)%3f%5cd%2b)%3f)(%3f%3d%5b.%2c%5d*(%24%7c%5cs))%7c(%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5cs)%5b%c2%b1%2b-%5d%3f((%5b1-9%5d%7b1%2c3%7d(%2c%5cd%7b3%7d)*%7c0)(%5c.%5cd*)%3f(%5beE%5d(xp)%3f%5cd%2b)%3f)(%3f%3d%5b.%2c%5d*(%24%7c%5cs))&i=123+%3b+1.234.567+%3b+12.345.678+%3b+123.456.789+%3b+1.234.567%2c89+%3b+1.234%2c56789+%3b+1%2c2+%3b+0%2c123%0d%0a1%2c234%2c567+%3b+12%2c345%2c678+%3b+123%2c456%2c789+%3b+1%2c234%2c567.89+%3b+1%2c234.56789+%3b+1.2+%3b+0.123%0d%0aMy+numbers+are+123%2c456%2c789.89%2c+0.123+and+123.456.789%2c89.+&o=n)

[image]

You can also add the `RegexOptions.Ignorecase` flag and replace `[eE](xp)?` with `e(xp)?` to further shorten the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace

```
\.$  (dot at the line end)
```

with

```
\s$  (whitespace at the line end)
```

That should solve your problem. Good luck.